# How can a Data-Driven Radial Chart be achieved in .Net?

Tags: .net, tree, components, diagram, radial

I want to create a data driven diagram/chart/image like the one here

[image]

Is there any .Net component which can help me to create this.
I've searched and this diagram is called by different names like Radial Tree, Peacock Table, Relationship diagram etc.
I have to basically show relationship between a set of records (like A is connects to  B 20 times, C -> D 40 times etc.)
Any help would be welcome,
Thanks
Nitin :)

Comment: I haven't used it, so I'll recommend this by a comment, but http://www.graphviz.org/ seems to be an industry standard and there are plenty of C# bindings for it. You might find it useful.

Comment: Thanks Juliet, i wish there was a well supported .Net component on which i can rely for production app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using Syncfusion Controls, work very well